# Web API with Blazor (server side)

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, blazor-server-side

I have gotten a Web API service up and running and receiving/returning data to my Blazor application. But, what I would like to do is to receive real-time information back from the service so that I can display updates to the Blazor application on what stage the API call is in the process. I have done a little digging and I am confused if I should go with PushStreamContent, Duplex service, or a new SignalR connection back to the service call.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that this is the ultimate answer:

https://chrissainty.com/calling-grpc-services-with-server-side-blazor/